Riverpod Annotations Compiler Errors
I have attempted to add Riverpod to a Flutter project and use its annotations which then produce errors. I then created a new project and followed exactly what the Getting Started shows, however, those same errors are present.
I first installed:
flutter pub add flutter_riverpod
flutter pub add riverpod_annotation
flutter pub add dev:riverpod_generator
flutter pub add dev:build_runner
flutter pub add dev:custom_lint
flutter pub add dev:riverpod_lint

I then ran:
dart run build_runner watch

The code (please note the 2 errors shown below)
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

part 'main.g.dart'; <--- this generates an error: Target of URI hasn't been generated: 'pacakge:pods/main.g.dart' Try running the generator that will generate the file referenced by the URI.

@riverpod
String helloWorld(Ref ref) {
  return 'Hello world';
}

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child:MainApp()));
}

class MainApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final String value = ref.watch(helloWorldProvider); <-- generates the error: Undefined name `helloWorldProvider'. 
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

In my original project I tried all of the cleans and updates, etc to no effect. This is a totally new project that generates this issue immediately. It does work if not using annotations but I would prefer to use them if possible. How can I resolve these errors?

Have you run : dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs  ?

@2IIZ - Yes I did. Against both projects. Restarted, etc., The errors above persist.

The issue, as it turns out, is that I did not execute a "Save" for the file after the runner was up and going. So after executing dart run build_runner watch -d  I needed to File-Save for the part to be executed and created. Once that occurred, all worked as expected.
